# Swift: catch error case with parameters but with access to the error object

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, enums, try-catch

I would like to catch a custom error with parameters, but also get access to the error to call some function on it. How do you do that? (I don't want to just catch the CustomError and have a switch inside the catch block.)

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case error(code: Int) 
    func describe() -> String {
        ...
    }
}
...

do {
    try bad()
} catch let error as CustomError.error(let code) { // This doesn't work
    print(error.describe())
} catch { 
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit repetitive, but after reading through the language reference, I don't think there is a way to elegantly do this:

```
do {
    try bad()
} catch CustomError.error(let code) {
    print(CustomError.error(code: code).describe())
} catch {

}
```

This makes use of the fact that `code` and the case `.error` are the only 2 pieces of state that `CustomError` has. This means that we can recreate the error object, and call `describe` on that.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct as this is probably the best solution though it's a bit verbose, especially when there are many pieces of state. But it's still better than putting the describe-function outside the enum or having the describe-functionality scattered all over the code.